# Allow entering text except the space occupied by the image in UITextview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextview, cursor-position

In my application I have a `UITextView`. In that `UITextView`, when I click camera button in the toolbar, I am getting two options: use photos or take new photo. Then I add the taken photo by creating a `UIImageview` with frame (cursor.x,cursor.y,90,90) in `UITextView`. after I add the image. If I type in keypad that letters print behind the image.

How can I avoid this to print text next to that image and disallow the cursor to go to print behind the image?

I need to move the cursor to the end of `UIImageview` position. 
Is it possible?

Comment: @mou - please can you fix all the issue when you suggest an edit, not just the quick stuff.